# Enable/Disable placemarks from kml files in the Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: {lat: 37.06, lng: -95.68}
  });
  var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://googlemaps.github.io/kml-samples/kml/Placemark/placemark.kml',
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    map: map
  });
}
```

A simple example of loading a KML file, which will display the placemarks on the map, taken from: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml-features

My question is, how can I toggle the placemarks? I want to have all of them disabled at first, but as I run tests, searches, or whatever, I can have certain ones displayed. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify the displayed placemarks in a KmlLayer dynamically.

Options:

1. use a third party KML parser like [geoxml3](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3) or [geoxml-v3](https://code.google.com/archive/p/geoxml-v3), they display the KML as native Google Maps Javascript API v3 objects, which can be hidden/shown dynamically.

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_categories_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/nzhistory_net_nzmap_locations_kml.xml)

2. import your KML into FusionTables and use a FusionTablesLayer, you can toggle the displayed objects by changing the layer query.
3. create dynamic KML on your server and display that using KmlLayer

Comment: Thank you very much. Looking at your example, it looks like you're disabling/enabling the placemarks based on what their `stylecode` is? This should work great.

Comment: In that example, the categories come from the KML `<Style>` tag Id property.